# Random image generator causing memory issues

Tags: memory-management, swift3, memory-leaks, uiimageview, arc4random

I have a random image generator within an app, however after 5/6 images have been shown in an image view, the apps memory usage is very high causing the didReceiveMemoryWarning() to run. However when the button is pressed quickly the app crashes.

[At the start of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OM1H.png)

[After 5 or 6 images have been generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMi2a.png)

[After didReceiveMemoryWarning() has been called](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U14OH.png)

The code that creates the images is

`@IBAction func RandomImage(_ sender: Any) {
        let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(56)))
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "image\(randomIndex)")
    }`

with the average image size being shown 600kb.

Is there a way to use or clear the memory more efficiently? Or am I miss using the UIimageView? Would it be best practise to load the image from a data object?

Comment: UIImage(named:) saves in cache the image (if it isn't already), and yes when you add 600k quickly it will (and would) generate a memory warning. Since there is no way to clear cache from images I would give a chance to get Data from the image File and convert that data to image instead of instancing directly from the name. As far i know, image from data doesn't save in cache.

Comment: Ok thanks! As you say, calling the images from data doesn't cache anything and is much more efficient for this purpose. Is there any advice on image sizes within apps(iPads). Is 600k unnecessarily big?

Comment: Any size could be necessary and unnecesary, it only depends on the use. Try processing images for web, before adding to your project.

Comment: Oh and learn about autoreleasepool, could be useful in this case.